# Spring 4 Rest RequestMappingHandlerAdapter not Saving Configured MessageConverters

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jaxb2

I am having a problem with configuring the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter; which is used in a Spring 4.1.4 Restful WebService configuration.  When I configure the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter message converters, it doesn't not use the message converters that I've configured.  I put break points in the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters)` method and on application startup I see this method being called three times.  The first two times this method is called it has the pre-configured message converters, one of which is the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.  On the third time, this method is called with my manually configured message converters via application-context.xml bean configuration. At this point, I am thinking that I have successfully reset the message converters with my own configuration; but that is not so because when I invoke my Restful WebService, Spring is calling the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter instead of the MarshallingHttpMessageConverter that I manually configured via application-context.xml.

So I need to know how to:

1. How to tell Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter to use my configured JAXB2Marshaller; which is configured to work with JAXBIntroductions,
2. Unregister the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter in Spring 4.1.4,
3. Tell Spring 4.1.4 when it see XML data to use MarshallingHttpMessageConverter instead of the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter,
4. Create my own custom version of Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter so I can give it the correct JAXB2 Marshaller; which is configured to work with JAXBIntroductions, or
5. Get the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter to only used the configuration that I give it.

Any help with any of the five options above would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Tonté

Comment: Are you sure it's configuring the same instance and that you don't have a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue.
You have to remove  from the context file.
Its overriding the converters even if we specified list of converters.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue.
You have to remove mvcannotationDriven from the context file.
Its overriding the converters even if we specified list of converters.